# When does a hexidecimal number pivot to letters rather than numbers

Tags: encryption, hex

Assume this number `173250103518582539668252657343418508842`, if I wanted to convert it to a hexadecimal number such that a 10 = F, 11 = E, etc. where are the breaks/how does that work?

I've done a bit of research online and I can't seem to find the answer. It's a really low-level question, I know.

6 characters in there's a `10`, would that be flipped to an `F` or would that get missed because whatever triggers the flip in the int -> string hexadecimal conversion happens another way?

Comment: There are so many resources available online that explain this in detail.  Have you searched at all?  At ~800 rep you should know to research before asking...  This explains perfectly and was in the top results: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/numDecToHex/

Comment: I did research. The condescension isn't necessary, you could have just kindly provided the link... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexadecimal is an encoding used to express binary data in base-16 where the ascending sequence is 0-9a-f (upper or lower case a-f), once character per 4-bits (4-bits has 16 possible values). Thus 2 hex characters per byte.

binary bits (msb on left) and hexadecimal:

```
0000 0
0001 1
0010 2
0011 3
...
1001 9
1010 a
...
1111 f
```

To say "10 = F, 11 = E" is not hexadecimal.

To encode the decimal number 173250103518582539668252657343418508842 convert it is a Big Integer and then hexadecimal encode the underlying bytes to hexadecimal.
or
To encode the ASCI string "173250103518582539668252657343418508842" to hexadecimal convert each letter to the underlying ASCII binary code and then encode that into hexadecimal: "313733323530313033353138353832353339363638323532363537333433343138353038383432".

See [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) and [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Aside: My first day as a programmer I had to know hex, binary and ASCII encoding, funny how things change.

Comment: Thanks Zaph. I made the mistake with 10=F, etc. I meant 10=A